# What is the science behind talent?

Tags: brain

So some people are better at doing stuff than others of the same age..in other words, they have talent.

So I am asking, what is the science behind talent? What is different in their brains than others which give them an advantage?

By talent I mean excelling in physical performances like sports and mental abilities like IQ

Comment: This is far too broad. What kind of traits/talents are you most interested in? IQ, social skills, physical performances etc? All traits differ to what extent they are determined by genetics, environment and gene/environment interactions, and our knowledge about different traits also differ dramatically.

Comment: I agree with @fileunderwater , this question is way too broad and shows no research effort whatsoever. There is plenty of literature available on this subject. One just needs to *search* for it (hint, hint)..

Comment: i DID search it but couldn't find very satisfying answers. And sorry for the broad question, I narrowed it down..

Comment: Excellent. Would you perhaps care to add some of the sources to your question? I mean the ones that you came across and found unsatisfactory. It always helps to create a better understanding.